# Preference Screen options (CheckBoxPreference and EditTextPreference) is not showing

Tags: android-activity, android-preferences

I am new to android. My Preference Screen option is not showing. I am following below tutorial section "Preferences" and "Creating the Settings Activity"(https://wiki.oulu.fi/display/esde/List+views%2C+Intents%2C+Preferences+and+Notifications)

This is my SettingsActivity.java class

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {


public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    private  SettingsFragment settingsFragment = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment)
        .commit();
    }
}
```

This is the settings for Preference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/server_settings" >
</PreferenceCategory>

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="@+id/pref_check"
    android:summaryOff="@string/pref_off"
    android:summaryOn="@string/pref_on" >
</CheckBoxPreference>

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@+id/pref_edit" 
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/edit_text_pref">

</EditTextPreference>
```

In the main activity I have below method for launching SettingActivity class.

```
//  launch the settings activity
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    return true;
}
```

Also I have added below code under main activity,  onCreate method to initialize the default values for the settings, from the preferences setting file

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

Could you help me on this issue?